# Corrupted memory. SQLite or Android bug

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-corruption

I get such stack trace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: someTa???: , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM someTa??? WHERE a = ? AND b = ?
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
```

Notice that the SQL is corruped, instead of **someTable** I see **someTa???**, where ? stands for char 0x1A. This happens only sometimes (very rare).

I create SQL query string using StringBuilder and String.format.

The question is who is corrupting memory? Is this Android runtime, or SQLite? May be this is a known bug?

Comment: as 0x1A is ctrl+z I would like to know if you use special characters as your table name?! (you came from russia, right?)

Comment: The table names are in english. Also, the generated SQL is 100% correct, since I generate the same sql each time (basically, it could be replaced with constant string).

Comment: Try replacing it with a constant string, then. Or, add some logging to write out your SQL before calling `rawQuery()`, to try to answer your question.

Comment: Actually I don't want to replace it with constant string (it makes my life simpler). Also, this happens only on user devices, and very, very rare.